# Symfony EasyAdminBundle v1.17.14: How to not show property in subclass of form

Tags: symfony, config, easyadmin

I have two Doctrine entities: Employee and AddressBook which are linked together by

**@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AddressBook", fetch="EAGER")**

Everything works fine as aspected, accept one thing:
If I don't want to show a single property in the Edit-Form of EasyAdmin, I can easily write something like this in my easy_admin.yaml:

```
- form:
    - fields:
        - '-thisPropertyWillNotShown'
```

If I want to show my subclass AddressBook in the Employee form, I can write:

```
- form:
    - fields:
        - 'AddressBook'
```

And EasyAdmin will render all properties of subclass AddressBook into the form Employee and all works and is fine **but now** I want to not show a property of the class AddressBook i.e. 'country' because it's not necessary in form Employee (the AddressBook class is still used elsewhere).

Can anyone help me?